# What regular expression is good for extracting URLs from HTML?

Tags: c#, regex, url

I have tried using my own and using the top ones here on StackOverflow, but most of them let matched more than was desired.

For instance, some would extract `http://foo.com/hello?world<br` (note `<br` at end) from the input `...http://foo.com/hello?world<br>...`.

If there a pattern that can match just the URL more reliably?

This is the current pattern I am using:

```
@"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&^]*)"
```

Comment: What's invalid about those characters?

Comment: HTML shouldn't be collected along with the urls obviously.

Comment: Why use a regular expression at all? `http://foo.com/bar?flub<blub` *is an entirely valid URL*. Perhaps this is an X-Y problem and the real issue is with how the URLs are used (e.g. when put in HTML output)?

Comment: _HTML shouldn't be collected_ ... ? I think pst is right, I think we've got an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on our hands. What problem are you _really_ trying to solve?

Comment: @Drake I do not know of a way to use a regular expression to reliably extract links (in all contexts) from HTML without restricting what an "acceptable URL" is. If the range of acceptable URLs is decreased (e.g. "can't contain <" or "can't contain <commontag"), then it may help with this particular error-rate.

Comment: According to RFC 1738, angled brackets should only be used to encapsulate a URL.

www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Comment: @Jason - Except malicious people won't stick to the RFC and the OQ was about the 'most secure way' to parse a Uri using a Regex.

Comment: Fair enough, but would @Drake really want to collect URLs with malicious characters?

Comment: @Jason - Shrug. I dunno what his use is. I do know that somebody might find this post later on google (which is the intent of SO) and think the regex is correct to use. </soapbox>

Comment: I would assume his use would be to not collect malicious characters (as he stated he does not want to).

That said, whether or not using a regex is useful is truly up to the developer.  That's why SO allows for multiple answers.  None are wrong--only one is accepted by the original asker for _his_ use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex needs an escape for the dash "-" in the last character group:

```
@"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+\-=\\\.&^]*)"
```

Essentially, you were allowing characters from + through =, which includes <

Comment: This collected thousands of blank lines and single words, I need a pattern that matches URLs not validates them.

Comment: mailto? ...custom handlers...?

Comment: @RitchMelton instead of (https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help), use (\w+)

Comment: @Jason - That stops matching anything. My point is that RegEx for this sort of thing isn't a good idea.

Comment: How would that stop matching anything?  \\w+ is equivalent to [a-z0-9-_]+ -- That would encompass (https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help) as well as any custom handlers you suggest.  Regex is actually quite doable in this case.

Tested using http://regexpal.com/ and it worked just great.

Comment: @Jason - Must be my test fixture then.

Answer (score 3):

The most secure regex is to not use a regex at all and use the System.Uri class.

[System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)

```cs
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2E");
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
Console.WriteLine(uri.PathAndQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static string[] Parse(string pattern, string groupName, string input)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        for (var match = regex.Match(input); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
        {
            list.Add(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupName) ? match.Value : match.Groups[groupName].Value);
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }

    public static string[] ParseUri(string input)
    {
        const string pattern = @"(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*";

        return Parse(pattern, string.Empty, input);
    }
```